# Save scroll position state for nested recycler views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a vertical `RecyclerView` that can have multiple horizontal `RecyclerViews` in the `view holders`. When I rotate the screen `view holders` are `recreated` and all positions of those horizontal nested recycler views are lost. How to keep those positions?

`configChanges` in android manifest is not an option.

`saveOnInstanceState` in every horizontal recycler view does not work because `view holder` is recreated.

Comment: You could use this library to save a scroll state for Nested RecyclerView github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save/restore list state manually:

Save:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

     listState = layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
     bundle.putParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY, listState);
}
```

Restore:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

    if(bundle != null){
        listState = bundle.getParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY);
        layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
    }
}
```